# How do I list the biggest tables in my single node cassandra instance?

Tags: cassandra

We have a cassandra test database that's been running great for a couple years. Today it started using gobs of CPU. After restart it happened again.

Since it's a **test** database with lots of crap - I just wanted to purge data from the biggest tables on the hunch that'll fix the issue.

This is a single instance running on a single server. What's the best way to figure out what the biggest tables are so I can TRUNCATE those?

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I came across solutions using nodetool where you get large dumps looking at blocks used, etc. This felt like a lot of work to sift through so the best I've come up with is to go directly to the filesystem (see below).

First I checked the logs and found some entries referencing where my data seems to be. In my case `/var/lib/cassandra/data/`.

```
ubuntu@ip-xyz:/$ cd /var/lib/cassandra/data/

ubuntu@ip-xyz:/var/lib/cassandra/data$ du -h --max-depth=2 | grep M
2.5M    ./tot_build_test/app_metering_id_activity_ts-55ac79a0d93a11eca73b09ac53055308
2.5M    ./tot_build_test/id_by_fingerprint-55c3f940d93a11eca73b09ac53055308
2.5M    ./tot_build_test/app_metering_by_id-5664cd20d93a11eca73b09ac53055308
7.7M    ./tot_build_test/onboarding_metrics_by_id-5552c0e0d93a11eca73b09ac53055308
5.5M    ./tot_build_test/onboarding_metrics_by_metric_ts-55f54270d93a11eca73b09ac53055308
9.6M    ./tot_build_test/app_tx_activity_ts-55d97d10d93a11eca73b09ac53055308
1.4M    ./tot_build_test/api_metrics_by_id-b6e4336086d811edafd7af4d63a260a1
37M     ./tot_build_test/metrics_by_metric_ts-b82351c0e8e511ec95cbc90b0480fbc7
53M     ./tot_build_test/app_user_activity_ts-56106b90d93a11eca73b09ac53055308
30M     ./tot_build_test/metrics_by_id-b8581d60e8e511ec95cbc90b0480fbc7
156M    ./tot_build_test
1.4M    ./system
21M     ./tot_localhost/metrics_by_id-9c91c090db7f11eca298336e81c9f198
2.1M    ./tot_localhost/id_by_fingerprint-fdae3ae0d93911eca73b09ac53055308
26M     ./tot_localhost/metrics_by_metric_ts-9c404530db7f11eca298336e81c9f198
2.2M    ./tot_localhost/account_metrics_by_id-fde29150d93911eca73b09ac53055308
4.8M    ./tot_localhost/onboarding_metrics_by_metric_ts-ff9d87c0d93911eca73b09ac53055308
21M     ./tot_localhost/job_activity-f091ca10a10811edb5af9735d3abddfc
2.2M    ./tot_localhost/account_metrics_by_metric_ts-fcec7180d93911eca73b09ac53055308
6.6M    ./tot_localhost/onboarding_metrics_by_id-fd0acef0d93911eca73b09ac53055308
1.8M    ./tot_localhost/app_metering_by_id-fe1cb420d93911eca73b09ac53055308
1.8M    ./tot_localhost/app_metering_id_activity_ts-fd61a180d93911eca73b09ac53055308
44M     ./tot_localhost/app_user_activity_ts-fcd39250d93911eca73b09ac53055308
8.9M    ./tot_localhost/app_tx_activity_ts-fd969430d93911eca73b09ac53055308
144M    ./tot_localhost
301M    .
```

In our case big is in the MB range but others may need to change the filter I'm using for grep above.

Anyway, from here I can manually pull together the keyspace (the first part of the path above) and the second part is the table name plus the hash.

My plan is to use a good old fashion editor to assemble a list of TRUNCATE commands using the keyspace.table addressing I come up with from the above, for example: `TRUNCATE tot_localhost.app_user_activity_ts;`

After running my TRUNCATE commands I was a little baffled that it didn't appear to do anything. Rerunning `du` - same result. What?! Basically cassandra was protecting me from being dumb - creating snapshots for those tables.

Never fear nodetool has a command to get rid of snapshots that is alarmingly easy to run (YOU PROBABLY DON'T WANT TO RUN THIS IN PRODUCTION):

```
ubuntu@ip-xyz:/var/lib/cassandra/data$ nodetool clearsnapshot
Requested clearing snapshot(s) for [all keyspaces]
ubuntu@ip-xyz:/var/lib/cassandra/data$ du -h --max-depth=2 | grep M
5.5M    ./tot_build_test
1.2M    ./system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86
1.8M    ./system
1.1M    ./system_schema
3.4M    ./tot_localhost
12M .
```

Ah... that's more like it!

This feels a bit brutish but I got to where I needed to go quickly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to check your `data_file_directories` location to find what's occupying the largest size, as you rightly did. And, as you mentioned, never fear to run `nodetool  clearsnapshot` to get rid of unwanted snapshots (& auto-snapshots from truncates, etc.,) from occupying the space.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach for getting the size of the tables on a node is to run `nodetool tablestats`. You should then parse the output of the command to sort the tables in order of size.

In your case where it is a single-node cluster, it is possible to simply write a shell script that would list tables in order of their directory size. Something like this script will list the 10 largest tables:

```
$ cd /path/to/cassandra/data_directory && du -sk */* | sort -nr | head
```

Note that backups (`snapshots/`) will be included using this method so you'll need to account for it. Cheers!